# Quartz 2.2 TimeZone issue

Tags: java, cron, timezone, quartz-scheduler

I want to schedule the cron job according to the specified  time zone. It will fire fine for first time but next time it will not firing according to the specified time zone rather it is firing according to the system's time.I am using the daily cron expression.it will fire daily at midnight 12:00 AM.
Below is the code sample of mine which i uses to schedule.

```
JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder
.newJob((Class<? extends Job>) Class.forName(cronJobClassName))
.withIdentity(JOBDETAIL_PREFIX + scheduleProcess, Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP)
.build();

CronTrigger cronTrigger = TriggerBuilder
.newTrigger()
.withIdentity(TRIGGER_PREFIX + scheduleProcess, Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP)
.withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 0 ? * 1/1").inTimeZone(instanceTimeZone))
.build();

scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, cronTrigger);
```

Thanks in advance.Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: You cron expression may not be correct for the day of week field. Try "0 0 0 * * ?"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had also tried "0 0 0 * * ?" this cron expression but still issue is not resolved.It is firing only first time according to time zone and then it takes the nextFireTime of system's time.

Comment: @user2819854 hey did you get the solution ....... Even i m facing same problem ..

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue(bug) with the quartz 2.2.0.Quartz 2.2.0 is unstable release.Try to upgrade to stable release of 2.2.1 it is available or you can downgrade to Quartz 2.1.7.